# calling await inside react native background timer setInterval when app is in background

Tags: react-native

I have an api call inside react native background timer setInterval and it cause the code excutation to pause. if I just do simple things inside callback it work correctly even if app is in background but if I use await keyword inside callback function, it pause the excuation. and when app become foreground all of task excuted at once

```
  const runTimer = () => {
    BackgroundTimer.start();
    timerInterval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(async () => {
      await callAnApi();
    }, 20000);
  };

  const stopTimer = () => {
    BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(timerInterval);
    BackgroundTimer.stop();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`react-native-background-timer`](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer)

It works even when the app is in the background.

You can find [here](https://medium.com/@loons.create/how-to-setup-react-native-background-timer-22263d655847) more details about the implementation

Comment: using await inside background timer cause pause

Comment: and I want to to not run the new api call before the last one completed. so I need some how an async setInterval